# Can I generate a JWT for my Spring Security app without have a user?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I want to generate a JWT with expiration date for people to access the system without have to register and create a user. Is this posible? I have tried with `JwtTokenProvider` but it needs a `LoginRequest to work` also with `Jwts.builder()` also needs a user.

Comment: What is the value of a JWT if anybody can obtain one?....

Comment: Remove the security from the endpoints that everybody can access

Comment: @RobOhRob There is a possibility of use case, where he will create JWT token and share it secretly with clients. In his case he don't want to distinguish clients i.e, users.

Comment: You can achieve it in filter. Where filter checks for header and read the Authorization header and sets authenticated = true, and authorities= just an empty arrayList and your all endpoints should **not** be hasRole but use `.antMatchers("/yourUrl/**").authenticated();`

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi why wouldn't he just have a login for his clients then?....

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi are these clients supposed to copy/paste the JWT into their request headers?

Comment: @RobOhRob Whatever information OP has provided is not sufficient to suggest any solution. We don't have any clear picture of his requirement. It looked me like, OP has exposed some APIs and API access to any clients/client application is given if it has token shared with clients. He has not mentioned how he manages to share token in case of token expiry. I have seen many applications where admin generates token and share the token with clients. Client applications  uses those tokens to access APIs and integrate data with their application.

Comment: @RobOhRob As far as JWT is concerned in context of spring security, you are right there has to be user and users token to take advantage of authentication and authorization which spring security provides. Without concept of user's token spring security becomes dummy as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> if you want to use spring security you can create security configration and extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Then important point is custom provider.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private JWTConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {   
      //you can write customAuth provider
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
      //Some ignore etc.

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable().and()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                //important here 
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/authentication/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter);
    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return this.authenticationManager();
    }

}
```

> This is Filter class which extends genericFilterBean. Every request is monitored in this class
>   You will check to it is right token
>
> I create token TokenProvider class and depend into JWTFilter then use valideToken method.
>
> if token is sended and not validate then throw exception
>
> if token is not sended then go super method so the flow is continue and works auth.authenticationProvider. Spring knows to start customAuthenticationProvider behind the scene becouse of you set into SecurityConfiguration class

```
@Component
public class JWTFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JWTFilter.class);

@Autowired
private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

@Autowired
private MessageSource msgSource;

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        //Resolve method is optional what you want to use
        String jwt = resolveToken(httpServletRequest);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt)) {
            //token validation is important becouse of expires date into token 
            // and you will check expired date 
            if (this.tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                String jwtMd5 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(jwt);
                MDC.put("jwt",jwtMd5);
                Authentication authentication = this.tokenProvider.getAuthentication(jwt);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        handleException((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse,ex);
    }
}

private String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String bearerToken = request.getHeader(JWTConfigurer.AUTHENTICATION_HEADER);
    if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        String jwt = bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        return jwt;
    }

    String jwt = request.getParameter(JWTConfigurer.AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN);
    if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt)) {
        return jwt;
    }
    return null;
}


}
```

> You can use this class for create token or validate token
>   you define expire date for token expiration into create method.

```
@Component public class TokenProvider {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TokenProvider.class);

    private static final String AUTHORITIES_KEY = "auth";   
    private static final String WTS_USER_ID = "wtsUserId";  
    private static final String CHANNEL_PERMISSIONS = "channelPermissions";      
    private static final String APP_ROLES = "appRoles";

    private String secretKey;

    private long tokenValidityInSeconds;

    @Autowired  private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    @PostConstruct  public void init() {        

        this.tokenValidityInSeconds = 1000;
    }

    public String createToken(Authentication authentication, Boolean rememberMe) {      List<String> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities().stream().map(authority -> authority.getAuthority())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //Token creation format is this 
       // token will be three part important parts are claims and sign
       // claims refers to body to use datas
       // sign will use to validation
        return Jwts.builder().setSubject(authentication.getName()).claim(AUTHORITIES_KEY, authorities)
                .claim(WTS_USER_ID, ((JWTAuthentication) authentication).getWtsUserId())
                .claim(CHANNEL_PERMISSIONS, ((JWTAuthentication) authentication).getChannelPermissions())
                .claim(APP_ROLES, ((JWTAuthentication) authentication).getAppRoles())
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secretKey).setExpiration(tokenValidityInSeconds).compact();     }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {         Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();


        List<String> list = (List<String>) claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY);         Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = list.stream()
                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority)).collect(Collectors.toList());      Integer wtsUserId = (Integer) claims.get(WTS_USER_ID);      List<String> appRoles = (List<String>) claims.get(APP_ROLES);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();         List<ChannelPermission> channelPermissions = objectMapper.convertValue(claims.get(CHANNEL_PERMISSIONS),
                new TypeReference<List<ChannelPermission>>() {
                });

        return new JWTAuthentication(token, wtsUserId, claims.getSubject(), authorities, channelPermissions, appRoles);     }

    public boolean validateToken(String authToken) {        
     try {          

       Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(authToken);             
       return true;     

     } catch (SignatureException e) {           
   log.info("Invalid JWT signature: " + e.getMessage());            
       return false;        
    }   } }
```

> This is controller who anonymous people get a JWT token .You can give a new JWT token all request and this JWT has expires date becouse of you set a expiration date into provider class.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ApiResponse login(@RequestBody @Validated AuthenticationRequestDTO authenticationRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(new JWTAuthentication(
            RandomUid, RandomPwd, "anonymous"));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    String token = tokenProvider.createToken(authentication, false);
    return new ApiResponse(ApiResponseStatus.SUCCESS, new AuthenticationResponseDTO(token));
}
```